# When is $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{P_A} = \mathbf{A}$ where $\mathbf{P_A}$ is the orthogonal projection matrix of the column space of $\mathbf{A}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{P_A}$ as the orthogonal projection of its column space, is there a necessary and sufficient condition for $\mathbf{AP_A} = \mathbf{A}$?

Comment: The condition is equivalent to $A(I-P_A)=0$, thus equivalent to $\text{rg}(I-P_A) \subset \text{ker}(A)$. The first space is just $\text{rg}(I-P_A) = \text{rg}(P_A)^\perp = \text{rg}(A)^\perp = \text{ker}(A^*)$. Hence $A$ satisfies the condition iff $\text{ker}(A^*)\subset \text{ker}(A)$. Is that helpful?

Comment: And since $A$ and $A^*$ have the same rank, it is even equivalent to $\text{ker}(A) = \text{ker}(A^*)$. (This is in particular true for all symmetric matrices and all injective matrices. I don't know whether there are more.)

Comment: Thanks @jabo. To be honest I was really trying to solve this problem: If $\mathbf{BC}$ is a symmetric matrix such that $\mathbf{ABA}$ is well-defined, then show that $\mathbf{ABA} = 0$ if and only if $\mathbf{B}$ is of the form $\mathbf{C-P_A CP_A}$ for some symmetric matrix $\mathbf{C}$. I have solved the necessity already but somehow failed to do so for the sufficiency. Here's my attempt: For the suffiency: With $\mathbf{B}= \mathbf{C-P_ACP_A}$, then $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{C-P_ACP_A}) = \mathbf{ACA - AP_ACP_A A}$. If I could show that that $\mathbf{AP_A = A}$, then I am done.

Comment: Assuming that $\mathbf{ABA}$ is well-defined with $\mathbf{B}$ being symmetric assures as that $\mathbf{A}$ is a square matrix but necessarily symmetric.

Comment: Let me rephrase part of the question to see if I understood your problem: *Given two square matrices $A$ and $C$, such that $C$ is symmetric, show that $A(C-P_A C P_A)A = 0$.* (Is that correct? I don't see a reason to talk about $B$.)

Comment: Have you looked at some examples? It might be useful to consider the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, because it does not satisfy the condition $\text{ker}(A) = \text{ker}(A^*)$.

Comment: Yes. That's it! We need to show that $A(C-P_A CP_A)A = 0$. And, yes, I think $B$ is not necessary. Do you know some ways to do it? Where can I insert your point regarding your answer about kernels..

Comment: Test $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $C = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. If there is no error in my calculations we have $A(C-P_ACP_A)A = A \neq 0$ in this case, so the two matrices constitute a counterexample.